# how to protect the email sent by nodemailer from being forwarding

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, email, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer and nodemailer-express-handlebars to send emails from my applications. I am basically sending an email invitation from my mail service to the user I want to join the application. There are two questions:-

### 1. How to protect the emails so that the email can't be forwarded to anyone else so that anyone else can't get the email.

## 2. The email contains the invitation link, how to protect the invitation link so that it can't be copied and pasted to anywhere else.

Following is the nodemailer implementation, Plz suggest what should i add to my code so that the above two points can be achieved and i can make my sending mail functionality more secure, reliable and trustworthy.

```
var mailer = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host :'smtp.gmail.com' ,
  port :465,
  secure:true,
  auth:{
    user:email,
    pass:pass
  }
})


mailer.use('compile' , hbs({
  // partialsDir: 'views/header',
  viewEngine: {
    extName: '.hbs',
    partialsDir: 'views/header',
  },
  viewPath : 'views/' ,
  extname  : '.hbs'
}))


  mailer.sendMail( {
    from: 'Admin name <invitation-do-not-reply@mydomain.com> ',
    to: 'receiver email',
    subject: 'subject',
    template: 'myfolder' + '/email',
    context: {
      brandname:req.body.brandname,
      link:req.body.link,
      

    }
 },(err, response)=>{

  if(err){
    console.log(err)
    res.send('bad email')
  }else{
    res.send("good email")
  }
 })
```

Comment: There is nothing you can do to prevent someone from copying and pasting the contents of an email or forwarding it.

Comment: Make sure the link can only be used a single time.

Comment: You can't protect from copying or forwarding in email.  You could make a unique link for each email that can only be used once.  The "used once" feature must be implemented on the server that receives the link where it changes some state on the server after the link is accessed rendering it unusable again so future uses just take the user to some sort of "this link has already exceeded its single use" page.

Comment: oh thanks, for the idea

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to prevent any text you send another user from being sent to another user. If you control the email service the recipient is using (for example, you have an enterprise mail server and you forward the email through that) you might be able to see if the recipient forwarded the email using the same server, but it would be just as easy for them to copy the email to a thumbdrive and email it out of band.

Governments would be very happy if this kind of facility existed. :P

You could make the link one-time-use only, but that doesn't prevent the email being forwarded.

Answer (score 0):

As Dan Pantry said, the email is out of your control after it has been sent. The end-point your link goes to is not.

Set up your link in a way that uniquely identifies that person (in this case by email). This way if you send an invitation to john.smith@google.com and he forwards it to jane.smith@google.com, the user who owns jane.smith@google.com would not be able to take action with that email.

JSON example:

```
{
    "invatationId": "q3eq3-g35yhg3-hfrg53-b0h9",
    "email": "john.smith@google.com"
}
```